# How to update .Net Core Item Templates?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to update the .net core default class template which is located:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\DotNet\ItemTemplates\.NET Core\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs`

After updating I run `devenv /installvstemplates` but they never update.

I was able to update the ones in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\WebClass\Class.cs` just fine.

Comment: Wow, so this morning it now works.  So does the cache have some invalidation method that I don't know about?  Do you have to wait a day?